# Program is slow to respond and I need help cleaning it up

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to make a simple program that moves the cursor around the screen.

I can get the cursor to move but when I press 'q' the loop just keeps going. Also, the program will stop responding (exit code -805306369 (0xCFFFFFFF)) but if I wait, it works again. Should I be using objects somewhere? I need help with some cleanup and debugging.

```
from tkinter import *
import autopy
import time
import keyboard
from random import randint

root = Tk()
root.title("Mouse Mover") 
root.geometry("400x115") 
root.resizable(width=False, height=False)
windowWidth = 400
windowHeight = 115
positionRight = int(root.winfo_screenwidth()/2 - windowWidth/2)
positionDown = int(root.winfo_screenheight()/2 - windowHeight/2)
root.geometry("+{}+{}".format(positionRight, positionDown))   

def mouse_mover():

    while True:
        x = randint(0, 1000)  # integers for random location point
        y = randint(0, 800)  # integers for random location point

        autopy.mouse.smooth_move(x, y)  # moves mouse
        time.sleep(1.5)

        if keyboard.is_pressed('q'):  # supposed to break loop (it actually doesn't??)
            break

button_1 = Button(root, text="Start", font=('Helvetica Neue', 16), 
command=mouse_mover)  # change state to command=*name of function*
button_1.pack()

label_2 = Label(root, text="press 'q' to stop", 
background="gray", font=('Helvetica Neue', 16))
label_2.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

**Expected:** I should press the button on the gui and the cursor should move around the screen. To stop the cursor moving you press 'q' on your keyboard.

**Actual:** I press the button and the "mouse_mover" function is called and the cursor moves around like it should but then stops after 4 or 5 movements and the program stops responding or it moves once and then I have to press the button again. If I wait It eventually starts back up. When I press 'q' nothing happens and it keeps going.

**EDIT: FIXED** I changed the function to

```
def mouse_mover():

    while keyboard.is_pressed('q') == False:
        x = randint(0, 1000)  # integers for random location point
        y = randint(0, 800)  # integers for random location point

        autopy.mouse.smooth_move(x, y)  # moves mouse
```

Comment: `time.sleep(1.5)` is almost certainly the wrong thing to do inside a graphical program.

Comment: I've got to say, this is confusing me. But I like a good puzzle! I've checked everything except the autopy function, I've re-written it several times, and have so far not eliminated the error, but I'm still looking into it. Oh and welcome to stack-exchange!

Comment: @tripleee I removed **time.sleep(1.5)** its a lot smoother now. Still the problem of getting it to stop. Why is **time.sleep** not OK in graphical programs? Thanks!

Comment: Because you can't pause the program entirely while it is supposed to respond to events like moving the mouse or clicking on buttons.

Comment: @tripleee Ok thanks. removed time.sleep and now the only problem is that it stops on its own (then either waits for another button press or crashes) and has very slow response time when it comes to quitting the program using keyboard input. Are there any glaringly obvious problems I'm missing? Really appreciate the help!

Comment: Did you solved your problem? FYI, it's perfectly fine to: a) answer your own question (if you found solution), b) accept your own answer as solution